Micrometer counter into Grafana chart
Hi I have the counter that increments with the tags job.id and processing.status
Counter counter = Counter.builder("ri.procession.job.count")
                                .tag("job.id", String.valueOf(jobId))
                                .tag("processing.status", item.getProcessingStatus().toString())
                                .tag("processing.start", String.valueOf(startTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)))
                                .register(meterRegistry);
                        counter.increment();

Prometheus selects the right values (as I hope)

What I'd like to do is to display multi-dimensional series first grouped by job_id and then processing_status
The result in Grafana should be looking similar to this

I think that the problem is in data preparation because as I understood, they should look like



job_id
SUCCESS
FAILED_UNKNOWN




7300
15
10


7302
4
6


7304
3
3


7306
3




But I can't figure out how to achieve that. I've tried multiple "transform data in Grafana" but Im still not getting what I want
The closest was "Bar gauge" was this. But I was not able to separate the bars by job_id.


Panel: Bar chart. Then under query, Format: Time series, Type: Instant. Transformation: Join by labels (Value: processing_status, Join: job_id)

@markalex great! thank you! would you also know how to colour the bars by value? I'd like to colour the Errorous columns red

Check overrides. You can select something like Fixed color for color scheme of the column, and select desired color there.

As @markalex pointed out in comments, using bar chart:
Panel: Bar chart. Then under query, Format: Time series, Type: Instant. Transformation: Join by labels (Value: processing_status, Join: job_id)
is the solution. Thanks!
